# dropzone form action dynamic through angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, post, action, dropzone.js

i need to provide the url of action in the form from the controller, but for some reason i am not able to do this,
 this is my form code

```
<form name="myForm" action="{{URL}}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" style="background-color:#ededed; border:1px dashed">
    <div class="fallback">
       <input name="file" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

i get this error

```
POST http://localhost:62078/%7B%7BURL%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
c.submitRequest @ dropzone.min.js:1
c.uploadFiles @ dropzone.min.js:1
c.processFiles @ dropzone.min.js:1
c.processFile @ dropzone.min.js:1
c.processQueue @ dropzone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ dropzone.min.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Angular way to make an HTTP post request.
You should use the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl',
  data: {'form': yourForm}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: but i have to put that url in the action attr of the form, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`ngSubmit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) on your form.

> `ngSubmit` enables binding AngularJS expressions to onsubmit events.
>
> Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means
>   sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but
>   only if the form does not contain `action` attribute.

```
<form ng-submit="postData()">
    ...
</form>
```

In your controller, define the function that will to the HTTP post:

```
$scope.postData = function() {
    $http
      .post(url, { email: $scope.email, name: $scope.name })
      .then(function (response) { 
          /* Success */
          $log.debug(response);
      }).then(function(reason) {
          /* Fail */
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using dropzone with AngularJS

Use `ng-attr-` binding for the form element `action` attribute:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-attr-action="{{URL}}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" style="background-color:#ededed; border:1px dashed">
    <div class="fallback">
       <input name="file" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

> ## `ngAttr` for binding to arbitrary attributes
>
> Web browsers are sometimes picky about what values they consider valid for attributes.
>
> If an attribute with a binding is prefixed with the `ngAttr` prefix (denormalized as `ng-attr-`) then during the binding it will be applied to the corresponding unprefixed attribute. This allows you to bind to attributes that would otherwise be eagerly processed by browsers.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide -
>    Interpolation (ngAttr Binding)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes)